# Result of a sql query to a new table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

In the below sql query, the Subquery executes successfully,when trying to store the results of that subquery to a new table t_test.I am getting error as

Incorrect syntax near ')'

```
select * into t_test from
(select prm.RNumber,
case when pom.Category = 'Medicine'
    then pom.field
    end  as [Dept],
pop.branch
from tbl_pr_m prm join tbl_po_m pom on prm.rnumber = pom.rnumber
join tbl_po_p pop on prm.rnumber = prm.rnumber);
```

May i know, how to store the results to a new table t_test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to keep your outer query, you need to give the inner query a name as a table

```
select * into t_test from
(select prm.RNumber,
case when pom.Category = 'Medicine'
    then pom.field
    end  as [Dept],
pop.branch
from tbl_pr_m prm join tbl_po_m pom on prm.rnumber = pom.rnumber
join tbl_po_p pop on prm.rnumber = prm.rnumber) as originalResult;
```

Comment: Thanks, I got a new table t_test with your query.

Comment: The outer query isn't necessary IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Your original outer query does not seem to serve much purpose since you are just selecting everything from the inner query.  You can remove it, and then use the `SELECT ... INTO NewTable` construct:

```
SELECT prm.RNumber, CASE WHEN pom.Category = 'Medicine' THEN pom.field END AS [Dept],
    pop.branch
INTO t_test
FROM tbl_pr_m prm JOIN tbl_po_m pom ON prm.rnumber = pom.rnumber
JOIN tbl_po_p pop ON prm.rnumber = prm.rnumber
```

Note that if the table `t_test` already exists, you will get an error when running this query.